# Create a google fusion table for highlighting a cities with different color in google maps

Tags: google-maps, geometry, google-fusion-tables, geomap

I want to highlight a cities with different color in google maps. I found the solution with google fusion tables layer. But i have doubt in the creation of fusion table. i have planned to create a table with three fields 'zip code', 'city name' and 'geometry'. I have analysed about the geometry field value. it must be a KML format. But i don't know how to get the geometry value for each city(all the cities from european countries).

Kindly advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why my question was down voted? What wrong in my question?

Comment: Have you looked to see if the KML data at [gadm.org](http://www.gadm.org/) will serve your purposes?

Comment: I dont know about this site, that why i raised this question. you know about this concept so you told but i dont know. Down voting is very easy but gaining votes very tough. please understand the situation of who raising the questions.

Comment: @geocodezip Even the question maybe is not exactly redacted as SO editors like (it takes a lot of time on reading and experience to get to that point) this is a question I've seen around many times and your answer is what all we were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

you need to build queries under **FusionTablesLayer** style options.
Check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/fusiontables_styling#styling-via-the-google-maps-api

Answer (score 0):

I know it's and old one but as I was wandering where to find a source of KMZ limits on Countries, Regions and Cities, I've read @geocodezip comment and find out [gadm.org](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html) a good point to start getting that data.
Once you download the maps you need, it's fair easy to use it on Fusion Tables or Google Maps Api.